# the 'leftmargin' attribute is not working while using bootstrap : -

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

the 'leftmargin' attribute was not functioning  while  i was using  twitter bootstrap ,i am a beginner at it . 
i used it like this

```
<body leftmargin="value">
 </body>
```

i hope there are no syntax errors .
i have posted a repository at github , have a look at the calc.html file in this [link](https://github.com/Anurag-Ans/Calc-By-Ans)

please help me , the page is not looking good, as everything sticks to the leftmargin ,

Comment: You're using a framework that requires latest HTML 5 with attributes from the 1990's. Switch to CSS instead.

Comment: could show me how would i do that , and thanks for that advice.

Comment: The `leftmargin` attribute was never part of any HTML spec. It is one of the old browser-specific attributes used long ago. The main risk with it is that it might still work on some browsers (and have no effect on other browsers). Use CSS instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap already provides a folder for CSS files. Create your own *.css file there and link it from your HTML documents:

```
<link href="/css/my-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Then, edit `my-styles.css` and set your left margin using the CSS syntax:

```
body{
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

I can't explain you everything about CSS here but you should be able to find a decent tutorial out there.